# How to hide SQL auth from .jar?

Tags: java

I have an application with all sql done client-side so the username and password and all queries all stored in the application itsself.

1. Is this the way to do it or will the queries be done by server-side scripts only? and if so how?
2. If it's not the case, how do I hide my sql details from the .jar file?(so not in raw text)

Thanks!

Comment: This is probably not the answer you want:  move the sql to the server side.  If you don't already have a server side, create one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option (2) is basically not possible. If you create the queries inside the client's JVM and trigger those requests over the net, an attacker will always be able to trace those queries, either by creating a dump of his JVM heap where these queries are probably somewhere stored as a `String` or by intercepting the network communication. So even if you stored the queries in an encrypted file, all the information for decrypting those queries would have to be sent with the application and could be resolved by the attacker eventually.

Therefore, I would recommend you to build a proper back end. Use a webservice such as JAX-RS and do not send queries. (This allows you to limit the valid communication to a specified amount of *save* interactions while you can basically do anything when your user is allowed to send SQL.)

Comment: so how would I pass data between those 2?
Through sockets and then make a lot of functions that are called by the socket?

Comment: I would recommend you to use some framework for webservices to do that. I personally like Jersey which offers a server and a client API: https://jersey.java.net/